# Get a list of Monaco Commands/Actions IDs?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

Is there a way to get a list of Monaco's available commands/actions and their IDs, like `editor.action.formatDocument`?

There doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation and I'm struggling to find registered actions and commands in the VS Code repository. The Command Palette shows most of them, but there's no indication of their IDs if you want to manually call them with `executeCommand`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`editor.getSupportedActions()`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html#getsupportedactions) is what I was looking for.

You can use it like this to get a list of action IDs:

```js
let actions = editor.getSupportedActions().map((a) => a.id);
console.log(actions);
```

Which returns a list like this in my current Monaco setup:

```js
[
  "actions.find",
  "actions.findWithSelection",
  "cursorRedo",
  "cursorUndo",
  "deleteAllLeft",
  "deleteAllRight",
  "editor.action.addCommentLine",
  "editor.action.addCursorsToBottom",
  "editor.action.addCursorsToTop",
  "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch",
  "editor.action.addSelectionToPreviousFindMatch",
  "editor.action.blockComment",
  "editor.action.clipboardCopyWithSyntaxHighlightingAction",
  "editor.action.commentLine",
  "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
  "editor.action.copyLinesUpAction",
  "editor.action.deleteLines",
  "editor.action.detectIndentation",
  "editor.action.duplicateSelection",
  "editor.action.fontZoomIn",
  "editor.action.fontZoomOut",
  "editor.action.fontZoomReset",
  "editor.action.formatDocument",
  "editor.action.formatSelection",
  "editor.action.gotoLine",
  "editor.action.goToReferences",
  "editor.action.indentationToSpaces",
  "editor.action.indentationToTabs",
  "editor.action.indentLines",
  "editor.action.indentUsingSpaces",
  "editor.action.indentUsingTabs",
  "editor.action.inPlaceReplace.down",
  "editor.action.inPlaceReplace.up",
  "editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
  "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",
  "editor.action.insertCursorBelow",
  "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
  "editor.action.insertLineBefore",
  "editor.action.inspectTokens",
  "editor.action.joinLines",
  "editor.action.jumpToBracket",
  "editor.action.marker.next",
  "editor.action.marker.nextInFiles",
  "editor.action.marker.prev",
  "editor.action.marker.prevInFiles",
  "editor.action.moveCarretLeftAction",
  "editor.action.moveCarretRightAction",
  "editor.action.moveLinesDownAction",
  "editor.action.moveLinesUpAction",
  "editor.action.moveSelectionToNextFindMatch",
  "editor.action.moveSelectionToPreviousFindMatch",
  "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction",
  "editor.action.nextSelectionMatchFindAction",
  "editor.action.onTypeRename",
  "editor.action.openLink",
  "editor.action.outdentLines",
  "editor.action.peekDefinition",
  "editor.action.previousMatchFindAction",
  "editor.action.previousSelectionMatchFindAction",
  "editor.action.quickCommand",
  "editor.action.quickFix",
  "editor.action.quickOutline",
  "editor.action.refactor",
  "editor.action.referenceSearch.trigger",
  "editor.action.reindentlines",
  "editor.action.reindentselectedlines",
  "editor.action.removeCommentLine",
  "editor.action.rename",
  "editor.action.revealDefinition",
  "editor.action.revealDefinitionAside",
  "editor.action.selectHighlights",
  "editor.action.selectToBracket",
  "editor.action.setSelectionAnchor",
  "editor.action.showAccessibilityHelp",
  "editor.action.showContextMenu",
  "editor.action.showDefinitionPreviewHover",
  "editor.action.showHover",
  "editor.action.smartSelect.expand",
  "editor.action.smartSelect.shrink",
  "editor.action.sortLinesAscending",
  "editor.action.sortLinesDescending",
  "editor.action.sourceAction",
  "editor.action.startFindReplaceAction",
  "editor.action.toggleHighContrast",
  "editor.action.toggleTabFocusMode",
  "editor.action.transformToLowercase",
  "editor.action.transformToTitlecase",
  "editor.action.transformToUppercase",
  "editor.action.transpose",
  "editor.action.transposeLetters",
  "editor.action.triggerParameterHints",
  "editor.action.triggerSuggest",
  "editor.action.trimTrailingWhitespace",
  "editor.action.wordHighlight.trigger",
  "editor.fold",
  "editor.foldAll",
  "editor.foldAllBlockComments",
  "editor.foldAllMarkerRegions",
  "editor.foldLevel1",
  "editor.foldLevel2",
  "editor.foldLevel3",
  "editor.foldLevel4",
  "editor.foldLevel5",
  "editor.foldLevel6",
  "editor.foldLevel7",
  "editor.foldRecursively",
  "editor.toggleFold",
  "editor.unfold",
  "editor.unfoldAll",
  "editor.unfoldAllMarkerRegions",
  "editor.unfoldRecursively"
]
```

Comment: Worth noting that this does not include all actions shown in the context menu or command palette, such as "Format Document" / "Format Selection", if you call it right after creating an editor instance. There's at least some kind of delay in maybe the language loading where the other commands are then initialized.

Comment: shshaw did you succeed with taht ?

Comment: `editor.getSupportedActions()` works. If you call it too early, it may not show all commands though. Once you have the action IDs, you can use [`editor.trigger()`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html#trigger) to call them.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use:

```
let actions = editor.getActions();
console.log(actions);

let actions = editor._actions;
console.log(actions);
```